# Access data from arr of objects using props passed to children - error

Tags: reactjs

Using props passed down to functional component to access data from an array of objects. Getting the following result when the code is running.

I have tried assigning props.id to a variable and using that in its place but get the same error, why is this happening and how can I work around it/fix it?

**Object:**

```
const items = [
 {
  url: 'sample url 1',
  desc: 'Description 1'
 },
 {
  url: 'sample url 2',
  desc: 'Description 2'
 }
```

**Attempt to log the data:**

```
console.log(items[props.id].url);
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Comment: That means that `props.id` is neither `0` nor `1`. You are trying to access an array with two elements, so the array index must be either `0` or `1`. You can try for yourself with a fixed value: `items[3].url`, `items['foo'].url`, `items[undefined].url`. Solution: Make sure `props.id` is set to a valid array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` sounds a bit misleading here. What you are trying to do is to assign the index of an element to the variable `props.id`. The index can be (as you can read in the comment by Felix) be `0` or `1` since your array has two elements in it.

There are two options here:

1. Stick with using index

Call it `props.index` and make sure that `props.index < items.length` at all times to avoid Type and OutOfBounds errors.

2. Actually creating an id

```
const items = [
 {
  id: 1,
  url: 'sample url 1',
  desc: 'Description 1'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  url: 'sample url 2',
  desc: 'Description 2'
 }
```

and using `props.id` to filter for the id as follows:

```
const item = items.find(i => i.id === props.id);
if(!item) {
 console.log('this id does not exist!', id);
}
// now you can use the item
```